# ThreadState is Stopped. No exception. What's going on?

Tags: c#

in VS2008 I have a program and it occasionally has an issue where a consumer thread stops processing work. When I looked the ThreadState says Stopped. What caused the thread to stop? I didn't stop it. There were no exceptions. Seems really strange. 
thanks

Comment: perhaps the thread "ran out"? as in the process stopped of its own accord, and terminated gracefully ... ?

Comment: Can you post some code?  There could be any number of reasons, and whilst an exception may not have been thrown, it is possible that your code caused it to exit.  It's difficult to tell without something to look at!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the thread is terminated?

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx
a thread is in Stopped state only if it's terminated or if it responds to an abort request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there's no exception?

A `try` `catch` on your main thread will not catch exceptions on a worker thread.
In the starting method on the other thread, have a `try` `catch` block, then there either raise an event back on the main thread, or cache the exception on a property on the object that has the starting method, then check that property in the main thread.

Hope this helps.

e.g.

```
class Worker
{
    public Exception TheadException { get; private set; }
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do your thing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TheadException = ex;
        }
    }
}
```

....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Worker workerObject = new Worker();
        var workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(workerObject.Start);
        workerThread.Start();

        workerThread.Join();

        if (workerObject.TheadException != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Thread failed with exception {0}", workerObject.TheadException);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I learned something important here.  I've been mainly using the ThreadPool for threads since most of mine are short-lived.  In the `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` case, you can definitely handle the exception outside of the thread as long as you remember to call `EndInvoke`.  I was a little incredulous so I had to run your code to see for myself.  :)  I'm not sure why it's done this way.  To me, it seems inconsistent (I would prefer the latter way of handling), but now I know how to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used the ThreadPool, as most / all the threads we use will live for the life of a UI or Windows Service, but good to know about begin / end invoke. I'll have to have a look at that :)